# Change server time to local time that is sent by Facebook

Tags: c#, datetime, facebook-c#-sdk, datetime-format

I am using Facebook C# SDK to get some data from my Facebook page.

When I get objects of data, at that time I get one field:

```
created_time : 2014-05-23T11:55:00+0000
```

As it is not same as my current time how do I convert it to my current time or to standard UTC time?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Hint: parse it as a `DateTimeOffset`.) Are you sure that the local time zone on the machine you're running the code on is the one you want, btw? (If this is a web app, it may well not be.)

Comment: may be I will convert my time & this server time to UTC time then I can do what ever I want to do. But how to get time zone of datetime comming ?

Comment: That's what the "+0000" means... it's the UTC offset, which is 0 in this case. (This isn't actually a time zone, but it's probably all you need to know...)

Comment: @JonSkeet you're actually getting more advanced than necessary with `DateTimeOffset`, a plain `DateTime.Parse` will do.

Comment: @JonHanna: `DateTimeOffset` is the cleanest representation of what's in the string: a `DateTime` and an offset. From there, you can do whatever you like - but I fail to see why it's a good idea to throw that information away for no reason. When parsing, I generally want to *just* perform a string conversion to a nicer representation of the same information, rather than a string conversion and a transformation in one go.

Comment: @JonSkeet Because they only care about local time (what they want) and universal time (what they've got) and there's tonnes of code that works with `DateTime` that doesn't work with `DateTimeOffset`. If we could rebase reality, `DateTimeOffset` is how `DateTime` should have been designed in the first place, and often necessary (at least we don't need to roll our own any more), but in cases where `DateTime` suffices, I prefer to stick with it as the more widely used elsewhere.

Comment: @JonHanna: You can convert from the `DateTimeOffset` to a `DateTime` in whatever time zone you want as a separate step, and that separation makes things a lot clearer, IMO. As I say, I don't like parsing doing more than it needs to.

Comment: Oh facebbok is using UTC time only then I will just convert my time to utc time to compare both times.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can see your argument toward flexibility, and with knowledge of the wider needs of the application might indeed go with `DateTimeOffset`. I can't agree that this is "parsing doing more than it needs to", it's parsing that string as one of only two possible ways to fit it into a `DateTime`: Converted to Local (and kind set to local) or Converted to UTC (and kind set to UTC).

Comment: @JonHanna: And in both cases it's losing data. When I lose data, I want it to be obvious in my code, for the sake of anyone coming after me.

Comment: @vaibhavshah they are using UTC, and stating it in the string. The +0000 gives the hours and minutes the time stated is ahead of UTC. Both `DateTime.Parse()` as per my answer and `DateTimeOffset.Parse()` as per Jon's suggestion (that I at least agree is more useful sometimes for the extra detail) understand that string and act accordingly.

Comment: @JonSkeet almost all parsing loses data. Yours loses whether it was written as `2014-05-23T11:55:00+0000`, `2014-05-23T11:55:00-0000` or `2014-05-23T11:55:00Z`. That's fine because it's data you don't care about. Mine is also fine, if the further data it loses is also data you don't care about (may or may not be the case, I did after all mention the value of `DateTimeOffset` in some cases too, for a good reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the code:

```
DateTime.Parse("2014-05-23T11:55:00+0000").ToString()
```

returns

```
2014-05-23 12:55:00
```

Because 'DateTime.Parse()` understands the timezone in this string, and by default produces a local time. My timezone being Irish Summer Time, one hour ahead of UTC, that means 2014-05-23T12:55:00 for me, for you it'll be a different time depending on your timezone.

For the converse, to get the time parsed in UTC (more useful for behind-the-scenes web stuff or storage, rather than user interface), use `DateTime.Parse("2014-05-23T11:55:00+0000").ToUniversalTime()`

If you need to deal with timezones other than local to the machine the code is running on, or UTC, then you will need to use `DateTimeOffset`, with the exception that `DateTimeParse` will handle other timezones in the string, but from that point on only has the concepts of "local time", "universal time" and "unknown timezone".

Answer (score 1):

I would use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`, specifying the format string an the invariant culture:

```
DateTimeOffset value = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(text, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK",
                                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I strongly recommend this over using `DateTime.Parse` for the following reasons:

- This always uses the invariant culture. It's explicitly stating that you *don't* want to use the local culture, which might have a different default calendar system etc
- This specifies the format exactly. If the data becomes "10/06/2014 11:55:00" you will get an exception, which is better than *silently* guessing whether this is dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy
- It accurately represents the data in the string: a date/time and an offset. You can then do whatever you want with that data, but separating the two steps is clearer

The first two of these can be fixed by using `DateTime.ParseExact` and specifying the culture as well, of course.

You can then convert that to your local time zone, or to any other time zone you want, including your system local time zone. For example:

```
DateTimeOffset localTime = value.ToLocalTime(); // Applies the local time zone
```

or if you want a `DateTime`:

```
DateTimeOffset localTime = value.ToLocalTime().DateTime;
```

It's just one extra line of code, but it makes it clearer (IMO) what you're trying to do. It's also easier to compare `DateTimeOffset` values without worrying about what "kind" they are, etc.

In fact, I wouldn't personally use `DateTimeOffset` *or* `DateTime` - I'd use `OffsetDateTime` from my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, but that's a different matter.

Comment: `it's explicitly stating that you don't want to use the local culture, which might have a different default calendar system` <-- could you give an example or link whereby this goes wrong. i understand how it applies to Decimal, not DateTime

Comment: @wal: In this particular case, `DateTime.Parse` *may* detect that this is an ISO-8601-like format, and parse it using the Gregorian calendar anyway. But if you're in a culture like Saudi Arabia and you parse a date, it will apply the local calendar system, with different ideas of years etc. (For example, we're currently in year 1435 in the Um Al Qura calendar.) I prefer to be very explicit that this is *not* a "user generated" format string; it's machine-to-machine communication, so should use the invariant culture.